# store multiple data in access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I want to store data from shopping cart of a customer example: online pizza shop.Suppose a customer buys 5 units of pizza no 1 and 3 units of pizza no 2.So how to store it in Ms Access as if admin can see what has been ordered and in what quantity?

My view cart form looks like below:

[image]

Comment: Store it in a table, that is how you store "things" in MsAccess.

Comment: for every order should i create a new table?

Comment: Noooo, single table called orders.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you should have a `Products` table which includes `product_id` as primary key.  This is where you will store additional product attributes: name; description; price; etc.

Customer data could be stored in a separate table, `Customers`, which includes `customer_id` as primary key.

Then an `Orders` table would include an autonumber `order_id` field and a `customer_id` foreign key.  The purpose of this table is to associate an order with its customer.

The items included in an order can be stored as separate rows in an `Order_Details` table.  Its fields would include `order_id`, `product_id`, `unit_price`, and `quantity`.  Although the price is also stored in the `Products` table, you store it again in `Order_Details` as the price which was in effect at the time the order was placed ... this is useful since prices have a tendency to change over time.